# Why is my pair of budgies fighting in a nest box?

Tags: behavior, aggression, breeding, birds, budgerigar

I have a male and female budgie. The female budgie has 5 eggs in her nest box and sits the whole day in it. Along with her, the male budgie also stays in the nest box with her. Sometimes, they act as if they love each other a lot! But after 4-5 days or a week, they fight like hell. 15 days ago, they fought so much that their blood was all around their nest. I think they fight for the nest box. I understand about the female budgie, but the male budgie fights with her so much that he doesn't allow her to enter into the nest box. Their fight is so intense, they lock their claws. Today, 2 out of 5 eggs were damaged. I don't want to split them because they are a couple. How can I make them stop fighting?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Do the budgies use the nestbox for other purposes than eggs? Maybe to feel save or sleeping? If this is the case, maybe the male budgie would need an additional one, so it will not disturb the female with the eggs?

Comment: Yes, the female budgie will obviously stay in the nest for eggs. But, the male budgie stays in the nest box and I observe him sleeping the whole day in it. Sometimes, I try to push him from the nest box into the cage but he sleeps in the cage too, and adding more about him is that he has become more aggressive. He was more active before attaching the nest box.

Answer (score -1):

They might be fighting for dominance as most birds will do this. In this case the dominance being who runs the nest box. The best chance would be to put them in separate cages and put the cages close enough for them to see each other but not close enough to injure each other. Then they might not fight each other. I would also put the eggs in one of the cages so one of the birds can keep them warm.